# Scripting inside a mapping

Tags: vim

Recently I create a mapping to toggle highlight search. That's simple but quite useful, something like `nmap ,m :set hlsearch!`. The only problem I've been facing is that sometimes I just get lost after pressing `,m`.

"Did it work?", "Is it now on or off?"… Common question from the panic of not receiving feedback :-)

So I thought that echoing a "turned on" or "off" would make me calmer. The big question here now arrived: is it possible to include a little script inside the mapping? I know I could create a function, but that's not my intention for this simple script:

```
if (&hlsearch)
    echo "Search Highlight On"
else
    echo "Search Highlight Off"
endif
```

I guess that I need to "escape" the newlines like in a preprocessor directive, maybe:

```
nmap ,m :set hlsearch!              \
    if (&hlsearch)                  \
        echo "Search Highlight On"  \
    else                            \
        echo "Search Highlight Off" \
    endif
```

But probably that's not the proper way, doesn't work and I don't even know if it is possible.

Another thing I notice is that typing things like `:if (1) echo "works"` doesn't work either, even though both `if` and `echo` are "colon" commands. It gives an error with `echo`. So do I need to separate each command in some way? Preceding `echo` with another colon didn't solve the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but I'd recommend against it.  A mapping links one or two key presses (`,m`) in your case to a sequence of key presses.  Therefore, to do what you want to do, you just have to type in the commands as you would if you were doing it interactively:

```
nmap <silent> ,m :set hlsearch!<CR>:if (&hlsearch)<CR>echo "Search Highlight On"<CR>else<CR>echo "Search Highlight Off"<CR>endif<CR>
```

Each `<CR>` is the equivalent of pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  The `<silent>` stops it from echoing the whole contents of the mapping to the screen, so you only see "Search Highlight On/Off".

The other way you can join commands (in some cases) is with `|` so for example:

```
:if (1) | echo "works" | endif
```

See `:help :bar` for more information on this.

**Do it with a function!**  It'll make things much more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Al, now I understand the role of a function here. Thanks for every tip, specially the `:bar`.

Answer (score 5):

No need to use `if` in this context. The ternary operator, `?:`, will do.

```
nnoremap <silent> ,m :set hlsearch!<bar>echo "Search Highlight ".(&hlsearch?"On":"Off")<cr>
```

Moreover, in this specific case, `:set-?` could be enough:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,m :set hlsearch!<bar>:set hlsearch?<cr>
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the alternative solution ;-) Quite interesting and simpler, I was not aware of the ternary operator in Vim.

Comment: One can use a terser version: `:nnoremap <silent> ,m :set hls! hls?<cr>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:nohlsearch

:set hlsearch! hlsearch?

:nnoremap <C-l> :<C-u>nohlsearch<bar>set nocursorline nocursorcolumn nolist<CR><C-l>
```

Comment: JA nie będę grzeszą więcej :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this in a way similar to the accepted answer:

```
map ,m :set hlsearch! \| echo &hlsearch?"on":"off"<cr>
```

but using the `?` operator instead of `if else` constructs.

Comment: Thanks @skeept . This was also proposed by Luc Hermitte

Comment: Opps, I missed it. I may delete my answer later.